# What does "I cannot be more thankful" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

What does "I cannot be more thankful" mean?

I want to say that I am very thankful for having this opportunity. Can I say something like the following?

> ... and I cannot be more thankful for having this opportunity.

Thank you

Comment: The immediate meaning is as the words imply, but the connotation depends on the context. Please supply the context.

Comment: I want to say that I am very thankful for having this opportunity. Can I say something like "And I cannot be more thankful for having this opportunity"?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but it would be more idiomatic to say "...I **could** not be more thankful."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase in the title conveys what it says: an inability to rustle up more thanks. However, the connotation depends on context: words, smile/frown, situation, etc.

It could mean that the little appreciation you’ve expressed is all you can summon, or that you’re so filled with gratitude that you feel like you’d float if you were any more thankful.

In your context, you are expressing sincere gratitude with the phrase, especially if the rest of what you communicate says likewise.